# javascript not worked for charts in browserfield OS5

Tags: javascript, blackberry, charts

The charts in browserfield not worked on balckberry OS 5.
There is any library that I can add it to support this code javascript and display charts or there is another solution.

Thanks for any reply

Comment: your question really isn't clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Show some code which is not working

Comment: I want to display web page contain chart. In OS6, this page worked fine, only in OS5 this page is not appear the chart. The chart is worked in java script. My question is there is any library add it to OS5 to support charts or there is a manner to create web charts supported on OS5 blackberry

Answer (score 0):

There is no library for older BlackBerrys. You're doomed to suffer on your own. BlackBerry OS6 uses a good WebKit-based browser. You'll get most of what you want working there.